# Meteor/Vue: Display result of search

Tags: javascript, vue.js, meteor, collections, find

I would like to add a search field to my app and show all articles from my Collection that match the entered value. The searchArticles method is called but the values are not shown as defined below the search field. What am I doing wrong?

Remark: After the comment by @Estus I changed the matchingArticles to be reactive. Still, the list of found articles is not displayed in the list.

```
<script setup>
import { ref, reactive, computed } from 'vue';
import { ArticlesCollection } from '../../db/ArticlesCollection';
import Article from '../components/Article.vue';
import { subscribe } from 'vue-meteor-tracker';

const articleSearch = ref('');
let matchingArticles = reactive({
  contents: [],
});
const searchArticles = () => {
  this.matchingArticles.contents = ArticlesCollection.find({
    text: articleSearch.value,
  });
};

subscribe('articles');
</script>

<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="searchArticles">
    <input
      v-model="articleSearch"
      class="border border-gray-300 rounded-md py-2 px-4 mr-2 text-gray-600 text-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-400 focus:ring-0"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Type to add new articles"
    />
    <button
      class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
      type="submit"
    >
      Add Article
    </button>
  </form>
  <ul class="list-disc list-inside p-4">
    <Article
      v-for="article of matchingArticles.contents"
      :key="article._id"
      :article="article"
    />
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: If the API did gave you some response then usually it's something to do with CSS. I would suggest you to go through the elements tab and check if the elements are actually rendered in the DOM. If yes then check wether z-index has proper value or width and height are being given to the container.

Comment: Hi, I checked the DOM but there is no ul entry showing up.

Comment: With a reactive framework there is plenty of JS that can go wrong that is more likely than a CSS problem...  I see no conditional rendering involved so if the `<ul>` element does not appear then I would expect none of this code to appear. Even an empty `<ul>` should still show in the DOM.  You still see other elements like the form and input?  If there's no console errors to report then a more involved [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is needed such as a github repo or codesandbox

Comment: Touché. I meant, no ul with one of the found entries. The "<ul class="list-disc list-inside p-4"></ul>" is shown.

Comment: matchingArticles is not reactive. This is what refs are for

Comment: Thanks, I read about that technique that I wasn't aware of. I did some adaptations in the code but still no result. What is still missing?

Comment: Shouldn't you call `this.matchingArticles.value.contents` instead of `this.matchingArticles.contents` on your `searchArticles` function ? Is this function well called on `form.submit` (like add `console.log` and see if it displays in console's output) ?